# MVC Webgrid Column with Form Does Not Pass Hidden Field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid

**The Problem**

I am using a webgrid with a custom column that has a form with one hidden field and submit button.  Looking at the HTML source, I see that the hidden field has a value.  The form submits and hits the correct HttpPost method in a controller.  The problem is the hidden field does not go with the post.

**The Code**

Here is the code that generates the webgrid:

```
WebGrid wgSearchResults = new WebGrid(
    source: Model.notes,
    rowsPerPage: 10,
    canPage: true,
    canSort: true
);

wgSearchResults.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All, numericLinksCount: 10);

@wgSearchResults.GetHtml(
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "wgSearchResults" },
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns: wgSearchResults.Columns(
        wgSearchResults.Column(format: (item) =>
            {
                System.Text.StringBuilder html = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

                html.Append("<form action='/ManageData/ViewFacilities' method='post'>");
                html.Append("<input type='hidden' id='hidBusinessId_' value='" + item.businessId.ToString() + "' />");
                html.Append("<input type='submit' id='btnViewFacilities_" + item.ID.ToString() + "' name='btnSubmit_" + item.ID.ToString() + "' value='View Facilities' />");
                html.Append("</form>");

                return new HtmlString(html.ToString());
            }, 
        canSort: false
        ),
        wgSearchResults.Column(columnName: "note", header: Sorter("note", "Note", wgSearchResults), canSort: true)
    )
)
```

The Model.notes structure is an instance list of this class:

```
public class SearchNotesResult
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public int businessId { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
}
```

The controller method this button hits is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewFacilities(string hidBusinessId)
{
    int businessId = 0;
    bool isValidNumber = false;

    isValidNumber = int.TryParse(hidBusinessId, out businessId);

    if (isValidNumber)
    {
        if (businessId > 0)
        {
            TempData["BusinessId"] = businessId;

            return RedirectToAction("GoHere");
        }
        else
            return RedirectToAction("DontGoHere");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("DontGoHere");
    }
}
```

In the above method, the hidBusinessId value is null.

**The Attempts**

1. Add parameter `FormCollection form` to above method (only contained the submit button)
2. Restructuring this column using Razor syntax (`@` with `<text>` tags).  No luck.
3. Research for hours.  That's why I'm here.

**The Options**

1. Changing this Post to a Get (and a different control like `Html.ActionLink`)
2. Add Business ID to button ID and parse in method
3. Any others the community suggests

Thank you for everyone's time!

Comment: You hidden input does not have a `name` attribute so there is nothing to be posted (remove the invalid `id` attribute and use `name='hidBusinessId'`). And you might as well remove the pointless `id` and `name` attributes from your submit button as well. And since its an `int` - then the parameter in the method should be `int hidBusinessId`,  not `string`

Answer (score 0):

What an incredibly stupid mistake...  The name attribute was needed instead of id.

```
html.Append("<form action='/ManageData/ViewFacilities' method='post'>");
html.Append("<input type='hidden' name='hidBusinessId' value='" + item.businessId.ToString() + "' />");
html.Append("<input type='submit' value='View Facilities' />");
html.Append("</form>");
```

Although the string datatype worked (please see my comment below).  Thank you Stephen for a fast and correct response!

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html!! (and the `name` attribute on your button is pointless) And posting and `int` to a `string` parameter and then manually converting it is just crazy.

Comment: Thank you for this comment.  I made additional adjustments (removed unneeded ID and Name values) and things still work as intended.  If the posting method's hidBusinessId parameter's datatype is changed from string to int, it's much easier to cause a system error by modifying the hidden field's value to a non-numeric value and submitting the form.  A system-wide error handling module can handle this (which I may do later).  Thanks again!